# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: и sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table:?

Tags: python, django

Я мигрирую проект, и мне выдается такая вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: account_profilemodel

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\user\Google Диск\bf\account\admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from account.models import profile, withdraw
  File "C:\Users\user\Google Диск\bf\account\models\withdraw.py", line 8, in <module>
    class withdrawModel(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\user\Google Диск\bf\account\models\withdraw.py", line 11, in withdrawModel
    base_obj = models.ForeignKey('account.profileModel', default = profileModel.objects.get(login='admin').pk, on_delete = models.SET_DEFAULT)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 425, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1303, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\wwwkaba\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: account_profilemodel
```

models

```
from django.db import models



# основные данные пользователя
class profileModel(models.Model):


    # личные данные
    # личные данные

    name = models.CharField('Имя и отчество', max_length = 40, null = True, blank = True, )

    birthdate = models.DateField('Дата рождения', null = True, blank = True, )

    login = models.CharField('Логин', max_length = 40, null = True, unique = True, )

    # пароль не случайно длинней
    password = models.CharField('Пароль', max_length = 30, null = True, )


    # автоматически сохранит дату регистрации
    date_reg = models.DateField('Дата регистрации', auto_now_add=True, null = True, )



    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Профили'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Профиль'
```

admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from account.models import profile


# профили
admin.site.register(profile.profileModel)
```

setting

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Причем каталог `migrations` не изменяется.

Comment: В traceback видно, что в файле `bf\account\models\withdraw.py` в строке 11 вы написали вопиюще некорректный default

Comment: @andreymal благодарю, это ответ. Могу я оформить его, чтобы при лайке его бонус давали вам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@andreymal
В traceback видно, что в файле bf\account\models\withdraw.pyв строке 11 вы написали вопиюще некорректный по умолчанию
Общий ответ от @andreymal